# Improve programming skills by games development

Tags: c#

I want to improve my programming skills, and I believe that games programming is the best approach for improving my programming skills.

Can you please guide me to getting started with some very basic/little games (with source code of course) like [tic-tac-toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe), etc. and then to some hi-fi games like chess or [Snakes and Ladders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_ladders).

Comment: Might be worth looking at SourceForge for some simple games with code. In terms of whether games programming is a suitable medium for practice, that would depend on your current level of ability.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can google for that type of material. Try googling for C# source code examples with the title of the game you wish to see an example of.

Comment: If I had to google, I would never have come here. thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: That's why I have roughly 200 answers but only 3 questions ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to improve your programming skills, which includes your analytical skills... asking for source code is probably counter productive.

You know how to play tic-tac-toe, you know the rules of each chess piece.

If you really want to improve your skills, you will attempt to implement them without source code.

Logically you know tic-tac-toe has a 3 by 3 board, so you'll need to set up that data structure and decide how you're going to store whether each cell is empty, an O, or an X.  You'll have to pick how each player will make their move, who goes first, and check for the win & tie conditions.

Comment: hmm, that sounds very good. I once started working on tic tac toe, but I could never figure out where to start, how many classes will be there, how would they interact with the UI etc etc. :s

Comment: And then look at source code after you have completed. That will be very worthwhile.

Comment: And then go do another project, come back a few months later and look at your source again. Refactor it with what you know and look at what's changed. Repeat long enough and you may reach enlightenment. :P

Comment: @Zain that's good :)   For something like tic-tac-toe, using classes might be unnecessary.  Try doing it first without worrying about design patterns or clean code.  Once you can do it manually, then you can abstract it out to using classes, and learn more about it.

Comment: any other game suggestion other than tic tac toe?

Comment: You can search the internet for literally Hundreds of card games. Just pick one and give it a whirl :)  Id not worry too much about graphics either, for just straight up logic flow consider printing out text to a console window that 'looks' like a tic tac toe board, or a card :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea quite some years ago now and this book was probably the most useful book I've read (it is VB.NET rather than C# but should be just as useful) - [Learn-VB-NET-Through-Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learn-VB-NET-Through-Programming-Experts/dp/1590591143/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1289595371&sr=8-1)